# Linked List data structure actual meaning of return Node itself

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures, singly-linked-list

why we can get pointer1's value by only using return pointer1 in the following code.

(I cannot understand why we don't need to use return pointer1**.value**)

Maybe because of some setting in the LinkedList class, but I cannot understand why.

file:LinkedList.py

```
from random import randint

class Node:
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None
        self.prev = None
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, values=None):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def __iter__(self):
        curNode = self.head
        while curNode:
            yield curNode
            curNode = curNode.next
    
    def __str__(self):
        values = [str(x.value) for x in self]
        return ' -> '.join(values)
    
    def __len__(self):
        result = 0
        node = self.head
        while node:
            result += 1
            node = node.next
        return result
    
    def add(self, value):
        if self.head is None:
            newNode = Node(value)
            self.head = newNode
            self.tail = newNode
        else:
            self.tail.next = Node(value)
            self.tail = self.tail.next
        return self.tail
    
    def generate(self, n, min_value, max_value):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
        for i in range(n):
            self.add(randint(min_value, max_value))
        return self

    def delDup(self):
        templist = []
        node = self.head
        templist.append(node)
        while node:
            if node.next not in templist:
                templist.append(node.next)
            else:
                node = node.next
```

file:returnNthNode.py

```
from LinkedList import LinkedList

def returnNthNode(ll, n):
    pointer1 = ll.head
    pointer2 = ll.head

    for i in range(n):
        if pointer2 is None:
            return None
        pointer2 = pointer2.next

    while pointer2:
        pointer1 = pointer1.next
        pointer2 = pointer2.next
    return pointer1
```

what I want to know is why I can use return pointer1 in the second file.
(I am thinking return pointer1.value is better but because of some setting in the first file, there is no need to use .value)

Comment: Does the caller of `returnNthNode` expect to get a `Node` or a value? Since the function is named "returnNthNode", it implies that it is returning a `Node`, which is what it's doing. I'm not sure if I understand what the confusion is.

Comment: Yes. I forgot to mention it.

I meant that what I want to know is the difference between self.head and self.head.value

for example, let's say,
currentNode = self.head
then
id(currentNode)
and 
id(currentNode.value)
is different output.

but, as I mentioned
print(currentNode)'s output is value itself.
it looks like same with print(currenNode.value).

So I want to know what is the difference of these two.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: `print(currentNode)` calls `__str__` to convert `currentNode` to a string. `__str__` just returns the string version of the `value` field. Change the implementation of `__str__` to see that `currentNode` and `currentNode.value` are different.